# The map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is differentiable, where $M,N$ are $m$-manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose the map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is differentiable, where $M,N$ are $m$-manifolds with $M$ compact and $N$ connected. If the degree of $f$ is 1, then $f$ is surjective?

Comment: A non-surjective map has degree $0$, because if $x\in N\setminus f(M)$, then $x$ is a regular value of $f$.